# Extra column on table vs size on disc

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

simple question ya'll.

I want add an extra float column to a data table which already has one million rows.

How much more storage on the server drive will it chew up for that one extra column?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default size of a float, [according to this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx) is 8 bytes, which gives you a million rows x 8 bytes added, roughly 8MB extra + space used for  indexes, if you need that.

Comment: Thank you Pedro! Just what I needed. Furthernote: I used a combination of SUM and sp_spaceused to do a calculation of my own. Most of the columns were NULL values so turns out extra column only increased 4.5KB on disk.